# Filter dict ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have this dict that was provided by ansible_facts

```yaml
  ansible_facts.lvm.lvs:
    lv-something-1:
      size_g: '70.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something2-2:
      size_g: '45.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something3-3:
      size_g: '250.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something4-4:
      size_g: '4610.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something5-5:
      size_g: '500.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something6-6:
      size_g: '25.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lvthinpool:
      size_g: '10666.11'
      vg: blockchains
```

First, I tried a lot to remove the `thinpool` item, but I was not successful, I tried to convert this dict to a list, tried to use `reject, rejectattr`, but they give just the names..  like this
I even tried to create two lists and make a concat but no success, lol

```yaml
  ansible_facts.lvm.lvs | reject('search', 'thinpool'):
  - lv-something-1
  - lv-something2-2
  - lv-something3-3
  - lv-something4-4
  - lv-something5-5
  - lv-something6-6
```

but I wanna catch the size of my volumes.. I wanna just remove `lvthinpool` to the dict, there is a way? and after that I will catch all size_g and I'll add up all your value

my dict expect output is:

```yaml
  ansible_facts.lvm.lvs:
    lv-something-1:
      size_g: '70.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something2-2:
      size_g: '45.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something3-3:
      size_g: '250.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something4-4:
      size_g: '4610.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something5-5:
      size_g: '500.00'
      vg: blockchains
    lv-something6-6:
      size_g: '25.00'
      vg: blockchains
```

I've be tried to use set_fact to convert this dict to a list and manipulate date with `reject` or `rejectattr`, then create two dict, and tried to union these values.. I've be tried to put the content to a file and delete it using regex with the `linefile` module

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample playbook doing `dict2items` before `rejectattr`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
      input:
        lv-something-1:
          size_g: '70.00'
          vg: blockchains
        lv-something2-2:
          size_g: '45.00'
          vg: blockchains
        lv-something3-3:
          size_g: '250.00'
          vg: blockchains
        lv-something4-4:
          size_g: '4610.00'
          vg: blockchains
        lv-something5-5:
          size_g: '500.00'
          vg: blockchains
        lv-something6-6:
          size_g: '25.00'
          vg: blockchains
        lvthinpool:
          size_g: '10666.11'
          vg: blockchains

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: 
      - "{{ input|dict2items|rejectattr('key', 'eq', 'lvthinpool')|items2dict  }}" #this will print desired data
```

The above playbook would spit below output:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "lv-something-1": {
                "size_g": "70.00",
                "vg": "blockchains"
            },
            "lv-something2-2": {
                "size_g": "45.00",
                "vg": "blockchains"
            },
            "lv-something3-3": {
                "size_g": "250.00",
                "vg": "blockchains"
            },
            "lv-something4-4": {
                "size_g": "4610.00",
                "vg": "blockchains"
            },
            "lv-something5-5": {
                "size_g": "500.00",
                "vg": "blockchains"
            },
            "lv-something6-6": {
                "size_g": "25.00",
                "vg": "blockchains"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter [*ansible.utils.remove_keys*](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/blob/main/docs/ansible.utils.remove_keys_filter.rst). For example,

```yaml
  input_sel: "{{ input|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['^lvthinpool$'],
                                                 matching_parameter= 'regex') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
input_sel:
  lv-something-1: {size_g: '70.00', vg: blockchains}
  lv-something2-2: {size_g: '45.00', vg: blockchains}
  lv-something3-3: {size_g: '250.00', vg: blockchains}
  lv-something4-4: {size_g: '4610.00', vg: blockchains}
  lv-something5-5: {size_g: '500.00', vg: blockchains}
  lv-something6-6: {size_g: '25.00', vg: blockchains}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    input:
      lv-something-1: {size_g: '70.00', vg: blockchains}
      lv-something2-2: {size_g: '45.00', vg: blockchains}
      lv-something3-3: {size_g: '250.00', vg: blockchains}
      lv-something4-4: {size_g: '4610.00', vg: blockchains}
      lv-something5-5: {size_g: '500.00', vg: blockchains}
      lv-something6-6: {size_g: '25.00', vg: blockchains}
      lvthinpool: {size_g: '10666.11', vg: blockchains}

    input_sel: "{{ input|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['^lvthinpool$'],
                                                   matching_parameter= 'regex') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: input_sel
```